# Uploading to a album of a page on Facebook using Android sdk

Tags: android, image, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Say i am the owner of the page "ABC" and there is an album on that page, called "XYZ" and this app is only for one person, me. 
I want to upload a picture to "XYZ".

So first thing i need to do is login using the Facebook account who owns the page.
Second i need `publish_pages` permission? Is that so? How do i get the permissions. And once i get the permissions, how do i post the picture to that album? Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: please do some research and testing first, stackoverflow is no place to get code (aka your work done for free), it´s a place for developers only and you are required to try stuff before asking. how to get permissions is explained well in the docs, and how to post a picture to an album can be found out with the api reference - there is even example code in the docs. hint: you need manage_pages and publish_pages, and you need to use a page token.

Comment: I already tried some stuff but i could not get what i wanted. I'll share the code if you want but it is useless. So just tell me one thing. I want to upload to a album on a facebook page. Do i need manage_pages and publish_pages permission or its just for posting to the timeline of the facebook page. Also, do i have to use GraphApi or shareApi ?

Comment: you need both permissions. posting is posting. not sure what you mean with graph api or share api, you don´t want to share a link, you want to post a photo, right?

Comment: Yes i want to post a picture, but to a particular album. I understood the uploading part but how do i upload to a particular album ?

Comment: see answer, i have added some links to the docs too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need `manage_pages` and `publish_pages`
- You need to use a Page Token of that Page
- Use the `/album/photos` endpoint to post a photo: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/album/photos#publish

Additional information about the Graph API in general and login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

Comment: Okay! Understood. Now the thing is i am developing this app for a third party,
And to get manage_pages and publish_pages permissions, i need to verify their business right ? So can i use my facebook developer account or do i need to make one for them ?

Coding part i understood very well, its just the facebook part that is confusing

Comment: you can use your account, and verify their business. just follow the wizards in the app settings, you can´t do anything wrong ;)